# Moving from Raspberry Pi to another platform?

Tags: python, diy

Lets say that I develop my highly complicated LED diode project on Raspberry Pi 3 B+ in Python. Now I don't want to use my RPi for this project becouse it is expensive and I want to move with next one, but I also want to have my diode thing work standalone.

Is there any cheaper, smaller etc platform where can I move directly my diode project to be standalone? I want to do this transfer with smallest financial and time cost and I don't want to use any C language microcontrollers etc, because I have done this on RPi.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: it depends on what "highly complicated" actually means

Comment: While the question certainly does sound like being off-topic, [Botspot's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/102194/19949) indicates that it is not. There are after all on-topic alternatives to the Pi 3B+ that might fit the bill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raspberry Pi zero is very inexpensive ($5), and is compatible with GPIO programs written on other Pi models.
[image: Pi ZERO]

Comment: Pi Zero W is $10, Pi Zero is $5